# BigQuery Issue with time query

Tags: google-bigquery

Could you please help me on this query: I don't understand why the TIMESTAMP_MILLIS is not working

```
    SELECT DATE, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN customDimensions.index = 1 THEN customDimensions.value END) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE, 
           visitNumber, 
           fullvisitorid, 
           device.deviceCategory, 
           hits.page.pagePath, 
           IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,            
           IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
           hits.page.pageTitle, 
           TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AS visitStart,
           TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1000 * visitStartTime + hits.time) AS hitStart, 
           hits.hitNumber, 
           hits.hour, 
           hits.minute, 
           hits.isEntrance, 
           hits.isExit, 
           CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid 
    FROM (FLATTEN([Table], customDimensions.value )) 
    WHERE hits.page.hostname CONTAINS 'X'' AND customDimensions.value != "null" AND hits.type = 'PAGE' AND (customDimensions.index = 1 OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11) 
    GROUP EACH BY DATE, visitStartTime, fullVisitorId, visitNumber, device.deviceCategory, hits.page.pagePath, hits.page.pageTitle, hits.hitNumber, hits.time, hits.hour, hits.minute, hits.isEntrance, hits.isExit 
    LIMIT 100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why the TIMESTAMP_MILLIS is not working. Could you please help me

The problem with your query is that you are using mixture of BigQuery [`Legacy SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) and [`Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) in the same query.

For example:
Below part of your query - is a Legacy SQL Feature

```
FROM (FLATTEN([Table], customDimensions.value ))
```

Whereas `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS` and `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` are functions supported by Standard SQL Only - you can find similar functions in Legacy SQL though (for example `MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` and `SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP()`)

You need to stick with one or another. Using [`Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) is recommended by BigQuery Team and I definitely second this!

Comment: Ok thank you @Mikhail Berlyant for your recommendation